# How to use Google Cloud FireStore emulator with NodeJS project?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use this tool in order to test my NodeJS application :

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/emulators/firestore

when I try to add something to the firestore database, I get this error :

```
Error: Unable to detect a Project Id in the current environment.
```

It is normal I think because locally there is no GCP Project.

I guess that I must configure firestore :

```
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');

const db = new Firestore({
  projectId: 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID',
  keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json',
});
```

When using the Google Cloud Firestore emulator, how may I create a "virtual" project Id ? 
Also, is the keyfile mandatory ?

The final goal is to use a local emulator for firestore if a "FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST" env var exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to setup and [start the emulator](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/emulators/firestore/start) in a separate terminal

```
gcloud beta emulators firestore start
```

Then for the project ID you can follow the documentation, and the github instructions:

```
firebase serve --only firestore
```

and then

```
require "google/cloud/firestore"

# Make Firestore use the emulator
ENV["FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST"] = "127.0.0.1:8080"

firestore = Google::Cloud::Firestore.new project_id: "emulator-project-id"

# Get a document reference
nyc_ref = firestore.doc "cities/NYC"

nyc_ref.set({ name: "New York City" }) # Document created
```

You can also check [this example here](https://claritydev.net/blog/testing-firestore-locally-with-firebase-emulators/)

Comment: Thanks. I found the same example ! 
A small tip is to use --host-port:127.0.0.1:8686 (port value for instance), because the nodeJS client don't accept the default ipv6 ::1:8686 notation :)

Comment: For nodeJs it looks more like :


`const firestore = new Firestore({
    projectId: "emulator-project-id",
    host: "127.0.0.1:8686",
        credentials: "",
        ssl: false,
        keyFilename: ''
    });`

Answer (score -7):

You need to use `express.js` framework with node js to make requests to `@google-cloud/firestore`, and best practices will be to start from https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started?hl=fa

Comment: Thanks, but I use express.js and all that good stuff but right now my problem is that I try to use the Google Cloud firestore emulator on my compute to develop outside the GCP. Any feedback on this tool ?

Comment: @google-cloud/firestore is a library, one cannot make requests to it. Additionally express.js is not needed in order to use this client, only Node is.